# Can't open Ubuntu 20.04 after installing alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, 20.04, windows-10

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F8KBdYx6VT/

Please help. I'm a student with zero Linux experience and I really want to learn more about it. I am using HP-Pavilion-15-cs3006tx with 1TB storage and 20GB RAM.

I installed Ubuntu 20.0.4 via USB drive. After installation, I removed the USB drive and clicked Enter. After turning my laptop on again, I am directly booted to Windows 10. I have been trying to solve this for the past 9 hours non-stop and re-installed Ubuntu four times already. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu, GRUB takes control - if you let it. Obviously you've installed your Linux somewhere, where you're bios doesn't even know that it exists. If you boot right into Windows, -there's no need to reinstall. Tell your bios where to boot. Or: You tell grub to install itself on the first partition (which partition did you select?)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the USB drive and boot into Ubuntu from it.

Once in, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
efibootmgr -o 0002,0000
```

Although efivarfs should already be mounted, it doesn't hurt to double check it.

`efibootmgr` will switch the boot order that your BIOS chooses. From your [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F8KBdYx6VT/), `0002` would be Ubuntu's GRUB and `0000` would be Windows as a backup in case something happens to GRUB.